# Unable to send the mail through contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I am using contact form 7 for my new website. But I am unable to send the mail through contact form 7. When I press the send button, I keep on getting the message: 
"Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method".
But When I see in the contact form db, I can see the data that I have entered in The form.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked that normal PHP mail() function is working on your new website?

Comment: Anything in your PHP logs?  Have you been through the list linked from the CF7 site (http://kb.cf7skins.com/contact-form-7-email-issues/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Localhost and are using wamp or zamp then Contact form is not able to send mail on localhost. You need to configure to send mail on localhost.

or else try to reinstall plugin and configure it settings again.